# How to 'key off' matching pairs in DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a df:

```
src    dest
LV       NC
LA       NY
NC       LV
NY       LA
```

how can 'key off' unique src/dest pairs so that they can be referenced to in a new column like so?

```
src    dest     pair
LV       NC       1
LA       NY       2
NC       LV       1
NY       LA       2

df = pd.DataFrame({'src':['LV','LA','NC','NY'], 'dest':['NC', 'NY', 'LV', 'LA']})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `tuple` + `set` then `factorize`

```
df['pair'] = df.apply(lambda x : tuple(set(x)),1).factorize()[0]+1
Out[69]: array([1, 2, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: that did the trick! can you explain what is going on with the tuple set x and factorize part?

Comment: @reeeeeeeeeeee tuple make it can be pass the python , set is order it ~

Comment: why is there a +1 at the end?

Comment: @reeeeeeeeeeee since the factorize will return the value from  0 to n-1 but you need 1 to n ~ that is why +1 at the end ~

Comment: by the way, when i added a dummy column to the dataframe with unique, non repeating values and then did this:
`df['pair'] = df[['src','dest']].apply(lambda x : tuple(set(x)),1).factorize()[0]+1`
the solution is non deterministic and only works sometimes. other times the pair column would be [1,2,1,3] when it should be [1,2,1,2]

Comment: @reeeeeeeeeeee try `pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values,1)).agg(tuple,1).factorize()[0]+1
Out[102]: array([1, 2, 1, 2], dtype=int64)`

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the data and use `groupby().ngroup()`:

```
df['pair'] = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df, axis=1))
   .groupby([0,1], sort=False).ngroup() + 1
)
```

Output:

```
  src dest  pair
0  LV   NC     1
1  LA   NY     2
2  NC   LV     1
3  NY   LA     2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group by `frozenset`:

```
df['pair'] = df.groupby(df.apply(frozenset, axis=1)).ngroup() + 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  src dest  pair
0  LV   NC     1
1  LA   NY     2
2  NC   LV     1
3  NY   LA     2
```

Comment: running that exact code gives me 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'ngroup'